# Any SVN GUI client for Mac is able to compare property changes?

Tags: macos, svn, svn-client

I have changed the ignore property in my SVN repo. But none of my SVN GUI clients can compare the property changes.
So when I view log, I am not able to figure out what property changes I have made.

Is there any SVN GUI client for Mac is capable of doing this?

I have tried CornerStone, SmartSVN, SnailSVN, XVersion.

BTW, TortoiseSVN is capable of comparing property changes, but it is a windows only application.

Comment: `/usr/bin/svn` is installed on my Mac, not sure if it's standard or if it got installed along with Xcode.

Comment: @tripleee I don't think that qualifies as a GUI client

Comment: @Thilo That's why it's a comment, not an answer.